# Mysql broken (14.04 -> 16.04)

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, 16.04, mysql

So I upgraded Ubuntu from 14 to 16 and now mysql-server is broken (iF). I tried a LOT of what was posted here, but none of it solved the error.

What I tried:

-> removing all mysql packages by purging them (dpkh- -l | grep mysql)

-> searching for "lost" config files (find / -name "*my.cnf*")

-> reinstalling mysql-server

-> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1571865

Install Log:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Systemctl Log:

```
* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-08-02 13:54:28 CEST; 21s ago
  Process: 19433 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 19430 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19433 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 19434 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           `-control
             |-19434 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             `-19493 sleep 1

Aug 02 13:54:28 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 02 13:54:28 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Journal Log:

```
Aug 02 13:54:58 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 02 13:54:58 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 13:54:59 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19543]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19544]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19548]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setu
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19549]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php > /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19543]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19544]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19545]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19552]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run > /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cr
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19546]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19547]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19554]: (www-data) CMD (! test -e /var/www/html/magento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /var/www/html/magento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19545]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19555]: (www-data) CMD (! test -e /var/www/html/magento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /var/www/html/magento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sendmail[19587]: u72Bt1WW019587: from=www-data, size=1538, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608021155.u72Bt1WW019587@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, 
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sm-mta[19588]: u72Bt1SO019588: from=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, size=1916, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608021155.u72Bt1WW019587@se
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sendmail[19587]: u72Bt1WW019587: to=www-data, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31538, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19546]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sm-mta[19591]: u72Bt1SO019588: to=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, ctladdr=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip> (33/33)
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sendmail[19590]: u72Bt1uw019590: from=www-data, size=1537, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608021155.u72Bt1uw019590@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, 
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sm-mta[19593]: u72Bt1Dc019593: from=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, size=1915, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608021155.u72Bt1uw019590@se
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sendmail[19590]: u72Bt1uw019590: to=www-data, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31537, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 CRON[19547]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Aug 02 13:55:01 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 sm-mta[19594]: u72Bt1Dc019593: to=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip>, ctladdr=<www-data@sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500.speedport.ip> (33/33)
Aug 02 13:55:06 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 org.gnome.Terminal[3487]: (gnome-terminal-server:6051): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_device_grab_add: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Aug 02 13:55:28 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Aug 02 13:55:28 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 02 13:55:28 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 13:55:29 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 02 13:55:29 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 02 13:55:29 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Aug 02 13:55:29 sebastian-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

MySQL Logfile:

```
2016-08-02T11:29:14.782162Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2016-08-02T11:29:14.782266Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2016-08-02T11:29:14.921627Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-08-02T11:29:14.921983Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) starting as process 10052 ...
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925629Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925652Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925658Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925663Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925668Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925869Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-08-02T11:29:14.925958Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-08-02T11:29:14.926957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-08-02T11:29:14.933633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-08-02T11:29:14.935158Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2016-08-02T11:29:14.948128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-08-02T11:29:14.948368Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html
2016-08-02T11:29:14.948406Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549217Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549276Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549289Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549296Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-08-02T11:29:15.549321Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549390Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549411Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-08-02T11:29:15.549965Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Yes i saw it, but the instructions require a working mysqld service. (and i already tried the Troubleshooting at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

So this is a quick and dirty solution:

Since the data stored in the mysqldatabase was not that important I purged everything from configfiles to databases in "/var/lib/mysql/* ". Now everything works again, so I assume the error has to be somewhere in "/var/lib/mysql/* ". I cannot reproduce the error (and I don't want to mess with my system again) so:

TL;DR: delete everything and install again